# TFS Security Group for Business UAT Testers

Tags: security, testing, tfs, azure-devops

I have attempted to setup a security group only granting access to the test plan section so that I can assign business users to this group to execute test cases within TFS. However, when I set DENY on all other permissions users assigned to this new group cannot see the test plans.

The purpose of this is to seperate these TFS users from my developers. Basically, I do not want them to have the ability to add/edit/delete code, delete user stories, bugs, or tasks.

I have tried various configurations for the new group I created 'Testing Group' and the following is the current configuration:

- Bypass rules on work item updates    `Deny`;
- Change process of team project.  `Deny`;
- Create tag definition    `Deny`;
- Create test runs `Allow`;
- Delete and restore work items    `Deny`;
- Delete shared Analytics views    `Deny`;
- Delete team project  `Deny`;
- Delete test runs `Deny`;
- Edit project-level information   `Deny`;
- Edit shared Analytics views  `Allow`;
- Manage project properties    `Deny`;
- Manage test configurations   `Allow`;
- Manage test environments `Allow`;
- Permanently delete work items    `Deny`;
- Rename team project  `Deny`;
- Suppress notifications for work item updates `Not set`;
- Update project visibility    `Not set`;
- View analytics   `Allow`;
- View project-level information   `Allow`;
- View test runs   `Allow`;

Users are unable to view the test plan to access the test cases and run unless I configure the 'testing group' as I have for my DEV team. However, that gives permission to the testers that I do not want them to have.

Comment: Please edit your question, so it'll be readable, not just plain text

Comment: Is `View instance-level information` set to `allow` in organization permission settings? Could you post a screenshot of the error message?

Comment: I do not have access to organization permission settings, only my project within TFS. I can only view and modify the permissions settings within my own project. However, I will email someone to have them check that configuration. Users assigned to this group are not able to view any test plans and therefore cannot view any test cases within those test plans. No errors unless they attempt to create a test plan which states you do not have permission to create a test plan.

Comment: Did you have someone check `view instance-level information` for the user? Any update?